# How to draw overview diagram in d3js

Tags: d3.js

I'm building a chart by d3js. I wanna add an overview diagram for my chart, like [Overview Diagram](https://gojs.net/latest/intro/overview.html) of GoJS. Unfortunately, I haven't found a same one for d3js.

Is there d3js code can do it?

Comment: Related, possible duplicate: [*"d3.js v4 minimap or how to have shared zoom on two elements?"*](/q/42886375). The term you are looking for is *"D3 minimap"*. Also try googling, there are plenty of resources.

Answer (score 0):

You may be able to use brush and zoom in order to achieve a similar effect.
Here is a Bl.ock by Mike Bostock himself which shows brush and zoom effect.
https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/f48fcdb929a620ed97877e4678ab15e6